# Want to write capture and re-transmit http/https request to Browser?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to write a simple Node Js application which will capture and re-transmit http/https request to Browser?

I have written the below code, but it works only for http request.

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req,res) {

    console.log("start request:", req.url);

    var option = url.parse(req.url);
    option.headers = req.headers;


    var proxyrequest = http.request(option, function (proxyresponce) {

        proxyresponce.on('data', function (chunk) { 

        console.log("proxy responce length" ,chunk.length);
            res.write(chunk,'binary');
        });

        proxyresponce.on('end',function () {
            console.log("proxy responce ended");
            res.end();
        });

        res.writeHead(proxyresponce.statusCode, proxyresponce.headers);

    });

});
```

Comment: You should use the `https` module for that, according to the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

Comment: I tried using https but its showing empty response in browser.

Comment: Can you share your code attempt?

Comment: BTW, your code seems to be attempting to request itself? Are you using `req.url` to make the request? I'm not sure how that is working exactly.

Comment: Above code I tried but it not working as expected. Any help will be appreciated.